# iOS Emulator Recorded Audio Stored On Localhost

Tags: php, ios, localhost, emulation, file-transfer

Recently I have developed an iOS app, testing on an emulator. De app records audio and I want to store the recorded audio on a web server. Since I test the app on an emulator I want to store the recorded audio on the localhost server. I have a PHP webpage that has a form to upload file and a script on the same page which handles the post method. I used that local webpage URL to transfer file from emulator to localhost server. I also did use file-transfer plugin and register it in the config.xml. It does not work so far. So my first question is: Is it possible to transfer recorded audio from an emulator to a localhost server? Or do I need to test it from an iOS device to a real shared hosting server? Thank you!

javascript:

```
var fileURL = "myrecording.wav";
var uri = encodeURI("http://www.localhost.dev/site/test/index.php");

var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey="file";
options.fileName=fileURL.substr(fileURL.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
//options.fileName="file";
//options.mimeType="text/plain";

var headers={'headerParam':'headerValue'};

options.headers = headers;

var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
    if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
        loadingStatus.setPercentage(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total);
    } else {
        loadingStatus.increment();
    }
};

ft.upload(fileURL, uri, win, fail, options);

function win(r) {
    alert("Code = " + r.responseCode + " Response = " + r.response + " Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
}

function fail(error) {
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code + ", upload error source " + error.source + ", upload error target " + error.target);
}
```

PHP script with form handler on http://www.localhost.dev/site/test/index.php:

```
<?php
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ): 
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    } else {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . " <br>";

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
        "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    }
  endif;
?>
```

Comment: You will require iOS device to upload to your server(local/any other).

Comment: means that I need to test it on an iOS device and not on an local emulator?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a real shared hosting server or an iOS device for testing, as long as you manage to set up the service you want to be using properly on your testing machine. If the form works from your mac using 127.0.0.1/whatever it will also work in the simulator. Try accessing the page in the simulator using Safari.